# Rails 5: Button to trigger controller method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use Rails 5 and MySQL.

I have an Imagecapturing page and want to make a button, when pressed, triggers a method call in my Imagecapturing controller. My attempt:

```
# imagecapturing index view:
<%= button_to "St. Gallen", action: "digitized_in_stgallen" %>


# imagecapturings_controller.rb
  def digitized_in_stgallen
    @imagecapturings = Imagecapturing.all.where("digitalisiert_in = 'St. Gallen'")
  end

#config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :imagecapturings
end
```

But I get an

> No route matches {:action=>"digitized_in_stgallen", :controller=>"imagecapturings"}

How can I make a click on the button trigger the "digitized_in_stgallen" controller method?

Comment: The code you posted doesn't have any relation to the error you're getting. Something is calling `ImagecapturingsController#create` and it's not coming from the snippets of code above.

Comment: yeah, it sounds weird but that's what happens when I press the button.

Comment: ok, I refactored the button_to method call. Now I get a more logical error message.

Comment: Can we see your routes file please?

Comment: resources :imagecapturings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a look at your routes file.

A quick fix is to update your routes file with this:

```
resources :imagecapturings  do
  collection do
    get :digitized_in_stgallen 
  end
 end
```

I'd really recommend having a quick look through the rails guides on routing here [Rails Routing Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html). You may find using paths easier to maintain in the long run rather than declaring the controller action.